# WPF: Calling TextBox.Clear() from LostFocus handler causes NullReferenceException when window closes

Tags: wpf

The sample below has two TextBoxes.   The second TextBox has a handler for the LostFocus event which calls Clear() on itself.  Changing focus between the two text boxes works fine; however, if the focus is on the second text box when the window is closed, TextBox.Clear() generates a NullReferenceException.  Is this a bug in WPF?  How can I easily detect this situation so I can avoid calling Clear() when the window is closing?

Edit: Possibly relevant - The window is the application's main window.  Test is not null at the time Clear() is called.  The exception is thrown from somewhere within the call.

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TextBoxClear
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Test_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Test.Clear();
        }
    }
}


<Window x:Class="TextBoxClear.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox LostFocus="Test_LostFocus" Name="Test" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Assembly references:

- mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
- PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
- System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Comment: Take into account that if the window is closed the textbox is disposed along with it, so Jason's answer would be a simple and good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Could the Test property be null by the time the LostFocus event is fired?

Try:

```
    private void Test_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Test != null)
            Test.Clear();
    }
```

**EDIT:** I'm having trouble reproducing the NullReferenceException with the code you posted.  Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Likewise, I can't reproduce the error. I've added an additional debug statement to the window close event, and it definitely fires after the text box lost focus, so I doubt that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hooking LostKeyboardFocus instead of LostFocus works OK for my situation and stops the event handler throwing exceptions.